# Is it possible to create an NPM script that runs without being installed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, atom-editor

I've made a little script alongside [HiFaraz](https://github.com/HiFaraz) to easily install best-practice packages for the [Atom](https://atom.io/) text editor. [The script](https://github.com/HiFaraz/atom-starter-pack/blob/master/installer.sh) just runs some `apm install ...` commands, and does not need to be installed to node_modules (or ever used again). We decided to add it to NPM to make it easier to find and slightly easier to run.

Is there a way to run-once and delete an NPM script? Maybe add a [post-install](https://github.com/HiFaraz/atom-starter-pack/issues/5) script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, better option to provide a link to the script itself which should be executed, like for example [zsh installation](http://ohmyz.sh/) `sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`. So in your case command should be:

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HiFaraz/atom-starter-pack/master/installer.sh)"
```

Comment: So you're saying unpublish from NPM and recommend a curl command instead? It's Faraz's package, don't know if he'll want to unpublish, but thank you for that command (didn't know you could do that). Any idea how to solve the NPM problem?

Comment: The package can delete itself by running `rm -rf ../` at the end of the script.

Comment: True, wouldn't it be better to use `npm uninstall ..` though? Do you know if this can be added to the `postinstall` script? Is there a better way than NPM postinstall? Something built-in & best practice?

Comment: Yes, you can also try `cd ../ && npm uninstall  %package-name%` which is much safer btw. You can place the main script to `preinstall` hook and uninstall to `postinstall` hook.

Comment: I'll try that out and let you know how it works. Probably won't be for a few days though. Thank you!

Comment: Still haven't gotten around to writing an uninstall script. But given that this isn't really the purpose of NPM packages anyways, I'm going to stick with the `curl` command. Thank you!